# I want to extend the SharedPreferences class in Android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'd like to create a extension of SharedPreferences from Android, so I can create some custom methods such as:

```
getBoolean (int KeyFromStringTable, boolean defValue);
```

rather than typing out:

```
getBoolean (getString (R.string.KeyString), defValue);
```

every time.

However, SharedPreferences isn't a class, it's an interface (dang).  Does anybody have a suggestion for how I might add some functionality to SharedPreferences??

Comment: use a decorator pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a wrapper that holds your `SharedPreferences` and adds helper methods.

Or, create static helper methods somewhere.

Or, create your own implementation of `SharedPreferences`, perhaps by forking the existing implementation. There are many downsides to this approach, not the least of which being that you cannot force Android to use your implementation, meaning places where it retrieves `SharedPreferences` (e.g., preference screens), it will not use yours. Also, you would need to track changes to the original implementation, in case any of those changes would be relevant for your fork.

Or, create some sort of keyboard macro that saves you the typing.

It's conceivable that there's some annotation-based way of handling this, but my annotation-fu is weak, and so I don't know all of the annotation capabilities.

Comment: I think found an answer in a different question: Create a class that encapsulates the interface to the Shared Preferences.  By doing that, I can add methods to the class with the behavior I want.  It's still under construction, but I'm optimistic.

Comment: I think that solution is basically what you're recommending in items 1 and 2.

Comment: @Rich: Mostly the first option.

Comment: Fair enough.  Thanks for the help.